# Bash array to JSON array

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to print all the string in the array delimited with comma

```
#! /bin/bash
clear
echo -e "Enter the list of hosts to print statement:\n"
readarray hosts

echo "======================================================="
echo -e "Enter the list to print"
echo "======================================================="

for i in ${hosts[@]}
do
 id="${i[@]}";echo [ ${i// /, } ]
echo $id
done
```

If these inputs

```
afrid.google.com
farid.google.com
```

My expected results is

```
[ "afrid.google.com", "farid.google.com" ]
```

But My result is

```
[ farid.google.com ]
farid.google.com
[ farid.google.com ]
farid.google.com
```

Comment: Your output looks like JSON, so use the `jq` utility.

Comment: could you please share what should i have to fill in ?? field

Comment: You don't put it in the `??` field. See the answer that someone posted.

Comment: you have 2 echo statements inside of your loop, of course you're getting 2 lines of output for each line of input! ;-) . Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).

```
$ jq -Rc '. / " "' <<< ${hosts[*]}
["afrid.google.com","farid.google.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A non jq answer, basically feeding the array through printf command with our formatting included (e.g. quotes and comma, then removing the the last chars from the string in the next command) :

```
hosts_str=$( printf '"%s", ' "${hosts[@]}" )
hosts_str="[ ${hosts_str: : -2} ]"
echo $hosts_str
```

Comment: Showing this error @mike

afri.sh: line 14:  -2: substring expression < 0

Comment: But when I try this it results the expected but with this exception, Could you advise on this


hosts_str=$( printf '"%s", ' "${hosts[@]}" )
hosts_str="[ ${hosts_str} ]"
echo $hosts_str

Result

[ "afrid.google.com ", "farid.google.com ", ]
[ "afrid.google.com ", "farid.google.com ", ]